# Having Issue on Making Button Drop-down Menu Full Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to change with of `.dropdown-menu` by percentage?

**Please test the code in Full Screen**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-group").hover(
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("slow");
        },
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width:700px;
  width:100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" >
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Without the Css, it is hard to tell why exactly, but the menu is 100% width of its parent element, not of the document object, its nested in 2 divs.Either way, you need to ost the css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add width 100% to class **btn-group**.
Add this to your css:

```
.btn-group {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want the button to span the full width too, then add width 100% to button.

```
.btn-group button {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-group").hover(
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeIn("slow");
        },
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width:700px;
  width:100% !important;
}
.btn-group {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" >
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </div>
```